# Flutter : dio package is not responding

Tags: flutter, error-handling, httprequest, dio

I use a reusable function which make simple dio request.

> Here is the function-

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:get/get_utils/get_utils.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
import 'package:pretty_dio_logger/pretty_dio_logger.dart';

import '../../config/translations/strings_enum.dart';
import '../app/components/custom_snackbar.dart';
import 'api_exceptions.dart';

enum RequestType {
  get,
  post,
  put,
  delete,
}

class BaseClient {
  static final Dio _dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
      followRedirects: true,
      maxRedirects: 3,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }))
    ..interceptors.add(PrettyDioLogger(
      requestHeader: true,
      requestBody: true,
      responseBody: true,
      responseHeader: false,
      error: true,
      compact: true,
      request: true,
      // maxWidth: 90,
    ));

  // request timeout (default 10 seconds)
  static const int _timeoutInSeconds = 10;

  /// dio getter (used for testing)
  static get dio => _dio;

  /// perform safe api request
  static safeApiCall(
    String url,
    RequestType requestType, {
    Map<String, dynamic>? headers,
    Map<String, dynamic>? queryParameters,
    required Function(Response response) onSuccess,
    Function(ApiException)? onError,
    Function(int value, int progress)? onReceiveProgress,
    Function(int total, int progress)?
        onSendProgress, // while sending (uploading) progress
    Function? onLoading,
    dynamic data,
  }) async {
    try {
      // 1) indicate loading state
      await onLoading?.call();
      // 2) try to perform http request
      late Response response;
      if (requestType == RequestType.get) {
        response = await _dio.get(
          url,
          onReceiveProgress: onReceiveProgress,
          queryParameters: queryParameters,
          options: Options(
            headers: headers,
          ),
        );
      } else if (requestType == RequestType.post) {
        response = await _dio.post(
          url,
          data: data,
          onReceiveProgress: onReceiveProgress,
          onSendProgress: onSendProgress,
          queryParameters: queryParameters,
          options: Options(headers: headers),
        );
      } else if (requestType == RequestType.put) {
        response = await _dio.put(
          url,
          data: data,
          onReceiveProgress: onReceiveProgress,
          onSendProgress: onSendProgress,
          queryParameters: queryParameters,
          options: Options(headers: headers),
        );
      } else {
        response = await _dio.delete(
          url,
          data: data,
          queryParameters: queryParameters,
          options: Options(headers: headers),
        );
      }

      // 3) return response (api done successfully)
      await onSuccess(response);
    } on DioException catch (error) {
      // dio error (api reach the server but not performed successfully
      _handleDioError(error: error, url: url, onError: onError);
    } on SocketException {
      // No internet connection
      _handleSocketException(url: url, onError: onError);
    } on TimeoutException {
      // Api call went out of time
      _handleTimeoutException(url: url, onError: onError);
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      // print the line of code that throw unexpected exception
      Logger().e(stackTrace);
      // unexpected error for example (parsing json error)
      _handleUnexpectedException(url: url, onError: onError, error: error);
    }
  }

  /// download file
  static download(
      {required String url, // file url
      required String savePath, // where to save file
      Function(ApiException)? onError,
      Function(int value, int progress)? onReceiveProgress,
      required Function onSuccess}) async {
    try {
      await _dio.download(
        url,
        savePath,
        options: Options(
            receiveTimeout: const Duration(seconds: _timeoutInSeconds),
            sendTimeout: const Duration(seconds: _timeoutInSeconds)),
        onReceiveProgress: onReceiveProgress,
      );
      onSuccess();
    } catch (error) {
      var exception = ApiException(url: url, message: error.toString());
      onError?.call(exception) ?? _handleError(error.toString());
    }
  }

  /// handle unexpected error
  static _handleUnexpectedException(
      {Function(ApiException)? onError,
      required String url,
      required Object error}) {
    if (onError != null) {
      onError(ApiException(
        message: error.toString(),
        url: url,
      ));
    } else {
      _handleError(error.toString());
    }
  }

  /// handle timeout exception
  static _handleTimeoutException(
      {Function(ApiException)? onError, required String url}) {
    if (onError != null) {
      onError(ApiException(
        message: Strings.serverNotResponding.tr,
        url: url,
      ));
    } else {
      _handleError(Strings.serverNotResponding.tr);
    }
  }

  /// handle timeout exception
  static _handleSocketException(
      {Function(ApiException)? onError, required String url}) {
    if (onError != null) {
      onError(ApiException(
        message: Strings.noInternetConnection.tr,
        url: url,
      ));
    } else {
      _handleError(Strings.noInternetConnection.tr);
    }
  }

  /// handle Dio error
  static _handleDioError(
      {required DioException error,
      Function(ApiException)? onError,
      required String url}) {
    // 404 error
    if (error.response?.statusCode == 404) {
      if (onError != null) {
        return onError(ApiException(
          message: Strings.urlNotFound.tr,
          url: url,
          statusCode: 404,
        ));
      } else {
        return _handleError(Strings.urlNotFound.tr);
      }
    }

    // no internet connection
    if (error.message != null &&
        error.message!.toLowerCase().contains('socket')) {
      if (onError != null) {
        return onError(ApiException(
          message: Strings.noInternetConnection.tr,
          url: url,
        ));
      } else {
        return _handleError(Strings.noInternetConnection.tr);
      }
    }

    // check if the error is 500 (server problem)
    if (error.response?.statusCode == 500) {
      var exception = ApiException(
        message: Strings.serverError.tr,
        url: url,
        statusCode: 500,
      );

      if (onError != null) {
        return onError(exception);
      } else {
        return handleApiError(exception);
      }
    }

    var exception = ApiException(
        url: url,
        message: error.message ?? 'Un Expected Api Error!',
        response: error.response,
        statusCode: error.response?.statusCode);
    if (onError != null) {
      return onError(exception);
    } else {
      return handleApiError(exception);
    }
  }

  /// handle error automaticly (if user didnt pass onError) method
  /// it will try to show the message from api if there is no message
  /// from api it will show the reason (the dio message)
  static handleApiError(ApiException apiException) {
    String msg = apiException.toString();
    CustomSnackBar.showCustomErrorToast(message: msg);
  }

  /// handle errors without response (500, out of time, no internet,..etc)
  static _handleError(String msg) {
    CustomSnackBar.showCustomErrorToast(message: msg);
  }
}
```

then I call a function like this

```
Future tryToFindCompany() async {
    userDetailsByCompanyList.clear();
    // *) perform api call

   
    await BaseClient.safeApiCall(
      "http://194.195.244.141", // url
      RequestType.post, // request type (get,post,delete,put)

      data: {"queryStr": 'eco.buet@gmail.com'},
      onLoading: () {
        // *) indicate loading state
        apiCallStatus = ApiCallStatus.loading;
        update();
      },
      onSuccess: (response) {
        // api done successfully
        // Convert the response to a list of UserDetailsByCompanyModel
        print("object is  ${response.data['data']}");
        final List<UserDetailsByCompanyModel?> userModels =
            response.data['data']
                .map<UserDetailsByCompanyModel>(
                  (jsonData) => UserDetailsByCompanyModel.fromJson(jsonData),
                )
                .toList();

        // Add the converted list to userDetailsByCompanyList
        userDetailsByCompanyList.addAll(userModels);
        // *) indicate success state
        apiCallStatus = ApiCallStatus.success;
        update();
        // Navigate to the next screen
      },
      // if you don't pass this method base client
      // will automaticly handle error and show message to user
      onError: (error) {
        print("Error occurred: $error");
        // show error message to user
        BaseClient.handleApiError(error);
        // *) indicate error status
        apiCallStatus = ApiCallStatus.error;
        update();
      },
    );
  }
```

but it stack. onError or onSuccess is not print. where is the problem ? how can I solve this ?